# simple css3 flex layout going vertical - not across

Tags: css, flexbox

I am having problems getting my css flexbox layout to work. I was hoping to get 4 boxes across the 1170px but I get a vertical layout. I have been testing in IE11 maxathon, and chrome

Here's the html

```css
.textwidget {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}
.ec-postcards {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.postcard-block {
  width: 20%;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<aside class="home-postcards">
  <div class="ec-postcards">
    <div class="textwidget">
      <div class="postcard-block ">
        <img src="wp-content/uploads/2016/03/alcove-units.jpg" alt="" />
        <p><a href="living">living</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="postcard-block ">
        <img src="wp-content/uploads/2016/03/alcove-units.jpg" alt="" />
        <p><a href="living">living</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="postcard-block ">
        <img src="wp-content/uploads/2016/03/alcove-units.jpg" alt="" />
        <p><a href="living">living</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="postcard-block ">
        <img src="wp-content/uploads/2016/03/alcove-units.jpg" alt="" />
        <p><a href="living">living</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ec-postcards-->
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: well, I seemed to have solved it but moving the flex css onto the text-widget... which strikes me as odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set flex to the wrong element. Should put it on the direct parent of the items you're trying to set next to each other. textwidget is the parent of the postcard-block, therefore that one should be set to flex.

```css
.textwidget {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.ec-postcards {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.postcard-block {
  width: 20%;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<aside class="home-postcards">
  <div class="ec-postcards">
    <div class="textwidget">
      <div class="postcard-block ">
        <img src="wp-content/uploads/2016/03/alcove-units.jpg" alt="" />
        <p><a href="living">living</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="postcard-block ">
        <img src="wp-content/uploads/2016/03/alcove-units.jpg" alt="" />
        <p><a href="living">living</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="postcard-block ">
        <img src="wp-content/uploads/2016/03/alcove-units.jpg" alt="" />
        <p><a href="living">living</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="postcard-block ">
        <img src="wp-content/uploads/2016/03/alcove-units.jpg" alt="" />
        <p><a href="living">living</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ec-postcards-->
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: yes - I just saw that you added that at the same time as I added mine. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Set direct parent to display: flex;

```
<div class="textwidget ec-postcards">
```